# Operating system and data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, windows-10

during installation of Ubuntu 14.04, I deleted all my data of my laptop including windows operating system! Is it possible to recover the deleted data and windows 10 operating system? If possible then how can i get them back?

Comment: Short answer NO. You can get some data back with lots of effort. If testdisk shows old partitions, you may be able to get files with names. Otherwise photorec may recover files & file fragments, but just by type not full filename. Often for Windows Windows tools work better. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247461 But this is why we always suggest backups before any major system change.

Comment: "With lots of effort"... well, not at all. It is quite easy to recover most of the user data. The OS, that is a totally different story.